# Two years of operating system upgrades (Android - one) - how is it implemented?

Tags: updates, ota-update, android-one

"Android One phones will receive at least two years of OS upgrades," according to [Google](https://web.archive.org/web/20200305201044/https://www.android.com/one/).

I interpret this statement as follows.

> An Android One phone will receive at least two major version upgrades for Android within two years of the device's launch date. For example, an Android One device that launched with Android 8.0 will eventually receive upgrades for versions 9.0 and 10.0.

Is this interpretation correct? Am I missing details?

To clarify, Android 8.0 was a *major* release; Android 8.1 was a *minor* maintenance release.

Comment: For example, if you have purchased an android one with Android 7, then you'll surely get android 8.0 and 9.0, also with monthly security updates of total 3 years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [android-one](/questions/tagged/android-one) phones are produced by multiple OEMs, so they are not governed by a fixed date of release. But they are *mandated* to provide two years of OS upgrades and three years of security updates. To remove the confusion of start date and end date, which is your question, see the fine print at the bottom of page you linked which says, OEMs should

> "Confirm exact duration of support for phones in your territory with smartphone manufacturer"

This applies **both** to OS and monthly updates as you can s from [Android One Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_One#cite_ref-one_19-1)

So, you need to check the OEM support for the region to be sure. However, since they are monitored by Google, you can be sure you will get updates as promised.

- The general trend is that they release devices into the market before/after the next major update, for example, if Android 8 is to be released in a few months, the phones out of the box come with Android 7 and are supported till update to Android 9. That said, how soon they release the next version is *a big variable*. Your best bet, would be to follow [Counterpoint comparison](https://report.counterpointresearch.com/posts/report_view/Individual/1418) or technical reviews /XDA

**Edit:** Post your edit to your question, yes, your interpretation is correct.

Comment: The fine print seems to reference the *security updates*, not the *OS upgrades*.

Comment: It refers to **both** — OS and monthly updates. This is what Android - one wiki (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_One#cite_ref-one_19-1) says while referring to the fine print *Concerning Android operating system (OS) **and** security updates the official Android One entry page says (in the fine print at the end of it):*